# Customer Specific Product module doesn't work in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have a problem with Customer Specific Product module in Magento 1.9. I installed the module but it works only when I am logged in with full privilege(full admin), if I make a new user role and I give this privilege for him doesn't work. 
I have two pictures to show you the problem. In the first picture I am logged in with the new role that I created and when I try to change the section to Customer Group Specific Products nothing happened. And the second picture shows what should be displayed when I change the section. In the second picture I am logged in with full privilege. 
[image: Logged in with restricted privilege]
[image: Logged in with full privilege]